# How to pass in variable for color in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a very basic java Swing window. I have an inner class ActionAndMouseListener which is listening for mouse clicks and such in a JFrame construction which has a large panel that changes colors depending on which of the three available buttons are pressed (red, blue, and yellow). The buttons are blank panels containing simply labels that read the name of which color they represent. I want this method inside the inner class to listen for mouse clicks and change the color of the panel when the button is pressed. I am trying to create a single method that will work for all three buttons. So far I have this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Object obj = event.getSource();
            JButton myButt = null;
            String buttonText = "";

            if (obj instanceof JButton)
            {
                myButt = (JButton)obj;
            }

            if (myButt != null)
            {
                buttonText = myButt.getText();
            }

            panel.setBackground(Color.(buttonText));
```

I know that passing buttonText as the Color variable is not going to work as it is currently. What do I need to change to make this work? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: A little bit off-topic, but I think you need better names for your `JButtons` :)

Comment: @Phantomazi No one is going to see this. Variable names are how I keep this stuff fun while I am learning.

Comment: @JoeSchmuck Pretty sure I see it.

Comment: @MuratK. You see myButt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the button you can do:

```
JButton red = new JButton("Red");
red.putClientProperty("color", Color.RED);
```

Then in the `ActonListener` you can do:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
Color color = (Color)button.getClientProperty("color");
panel.setBackground( color );
```

Or another approach is to create an instance variable for your class to contain a Map of the Colors:

```
Map<Component, Color> componentColors = new HashMap<Component, Color>();
```

Then you create the button like:

```
JButton red = new JButton("Red");
componentColors.put(red, Color.RED);
```

Then in the ActionListener:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
Color color = componentColors.get(button);
panel.setBackground( color );
```

Comment: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.awt.Color

Comment: I fixed the problem I think. What I have now is Color color = (Color)button.getClientProperty("color"); Everything seems to work with this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @JoeSchmuck `I fixed the problem I think.` - yes, I forget to include the cast in my "sample code". The idea of the code was to show you the concept. The compiler told you how to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

You could make a switch-case which checks the button-text and creates a color because of that:

```
Color color = null;
switch (buttonText) {
case "red":
    color = Color.red;
    break;
case "blue":
    color = Color.blue; 
    break;
case "yellow":
    color = Color.yellow; 
    break;
default:
    break;
}

panel.setBackground(color);
```

Comment: I think I can do what you suggested with just a series of if statements right? I am trying to avoid that sort of thing so the method will be accessible or usable and won't have to be changed if new colors are added to the main method.

Comment: Yes you can use if statements. But you will also need to add new if-else either way. So switch-case is much more "readable" in that context.

Comment: You'll have to change the method either way. It's easier to change the switch statement than adding an entirely new else-if statement...

Comment: @JoeSchmuck, `I am trying to avoid that sort of thing so the method will be accessible or usable and won't have to be changed if new colors are added ` - I agree, that is the better design approach.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to create a CustomJButton extends JButton. Something like:

```
public class MyJButton extends JButton {

    private Color color;

    public MyJButton(Color color) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
panel.setBackground(myButt.getColor());
```

Comment: This is closest answer to what I need that I have seen so far, but when I write this and call the getColor() method, the compiler returns an error that says cannont find symbol - getColor().

Comment: Make sure you replaced JButton myButt = null; with MyJButton myButt = null;

Comment: and make sure that you replace `instanceof JButton` to `instanceof MyButton`

Comment: @Christian So it should look like this? if(onj instanseof MyJButton) { myButt = (JButton)obj; } or should it be (MyJButton)obj?